# ngModel, dot-rule and more than one level of scope hierarchy

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's say I want to write HTML like:

```
<div my-directive my-start="topModel.start" my-end="topModel.end">
```

`my-directive` has a template that invokes other directives with `ngModel`, like so:

```
<div>
  <input ng-model="myStart" />
  <input ng-model="myEnd" />
</div>
```

I would like the inner inputs to transparently update `topModel`. It doesn't work this way, because there's no dot in the `ng-model` attribute and the value is set in local scope.

The only way I found so far is to watch both models in `my-directive` and translate, but it's a horrible abomination.

```
restrict: 'A',
scope: {
    myStart: '=',
    myEnd: '='
},
link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
    scope.model = { start: scope.myStart, end: scope.myEnd };
    scope.$watch("model.start", function(n) {
        scope.myStart = n;
    });
    scope.$watch("model.end", function(n) {
        scope.myEnd = n;
    });
    scope.$watch("myStart", function(n) {
        scope.model.start = n;
    });
    scope.$watch("myEnd", function(n) {
        scope.model.end = n;
    });
}
```

How can I pass the bindings *through* `my-directive` to the inner directives without all this manual synchronization?

**EDIT**: See plunker at http://plnkr.co/edit/ppzVd7?p=preview - this one actually works

**EDIT2**: See another at http://plnkr.co/edit/Nccpqn?p=preview - this one shows how "direct access" without dot doesn't work, and with dot and `$watches` does.

Comment: you are doing some thing wrong '=' is used for bidirectional update could you please set up fiddle demo or plunker demo

Comment: I don't quite see your problem, if you just bind to your scope vars it will [work](http://plnkr.co/edit/0bvg2J?p=preview). Could you add an example where you're having problems with this approach?

Comment: @Yoshi see the second plunker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your 2nd example I finally understood your problem, though I still don't think it's comming from breaking the *dot-rule*. You're simply mixing scopes / model binding (see `$parent.myStart`).

Try:

```
(function (app, ng) {
  'use strict';

  app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.topModel = {
      start: 'Initial Start',
      end: 'Initial end'
    };
  }]);

  app.directive('myDirective', function(){
    return {
      scope: { myStart: '=', myEnd: '=' },
      template: '<div>\
        <p>Start: <span special-editor-a ng-model="$parent.myStart"></span></p>\
        <p>End: <span special-editor-b ng-model="myEnd"></span></p>\
      </div>'
    }
  });

  // with replace
  app.directive('specialEditorA', function(){
    return {
      scope: true,
      require: 'ngModel',
      replace: true,
      template: '<input type="text" />'
    }
  });

  // without replace
  app.directive('specialEditorB', function(){
    return {
      scope: { m: '=ngModel' },
      require: 'ngModel',
      template: '<input type="text" ng-model="m" />'
    }
  });
}(angular.module('app', []), angular));
```

demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/SfFBf5NgFhSOQiFf5Emc?p=preview

Comment: It seems like `$parent` is doing the same thing as a dot, only pointing directly to a scope. It appears you tell the "lower" directive to use your scope as the `$parent`... This could work.

Comment: What if my editor is more interesting than that and it cannot use `replace: true` and thus merge in the `ngModel`, but has to update it through the controller like in the Plunker?

Comment: mhm, it seems I was wrong with my previous comment... I'll have a look.

Answer (score 1):

When you define the `scope` property as you do on your directive, you will automatically get two properties, `scope.myStart` and `scope.myEnd`, with a bidirectional binding to `topModel`. When you map them over to `scope.model` you break that binding.

Here is a working example:

```
module.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            myStart: '=',
            myEnd: '='
        },
        template: '<p><label>Start: <input type="text" ng-model="myStart" /></label></p>' +
                  '<p><label>End: <input type="text" ng-model="myEnd" /></label></p>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('myStart', function (val, old) {
                console.log('Start changed from', old, 'to', val);
            });

            scope.$watch('myEnd', function (val, old) {
                console.log('End changed from', old, 'to', val);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BHi5lYgxHFbo3fzsgpKz?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: I know I break the binding, that's why I have `$watches` translating between them. The problem is how to get it to work with that nested `ngModel` which needs a dot.

Comment: I tested this simplistic case and it indeed works. Let me see if I can find the difference between this and my real, less trivial case.

Comment: Hm, so the problem is if the directive's _template_ needs to use the dot rule due to directives that template might use, which otherwise might break the 'chain'. Not sure if that can be done without watches mapping values, but I'll see if I can figure something out.

Comment: I posted another plunker - this one actually shows the issue.

Comment: Is there a reason your `specialEditor` directive needs its own scope? http://plnkr.co/edit/W5LbCN?p=preview or if a new scope is needed: http://plnkr.co/edit/o3WC0y?p=preview

Comment: Btw, I guess the last example breaks eventual parsers or formatters you have added to the ngModel controller.